# Java ImageIcon to JLabel Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Why do I get an error when I try to set the ImageIcon of this JLabel to something.  It returns a null pointer exception.  Does anyone know the problem?

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel stick[] = new JLabel[10];    

    Window(){

        super("ThisIsWindow");
        setSize(650,550);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        stick[5].setIcon(new ImageIcon("stick.gif"));

    }
}
```

The error occurs on the last line of code that sets stick[5] to stick.gif.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
stick[5] = new JLabel();
```

before

```
stick[5].setIcon(new ImageIcon("stick.gif"));
```

---

Basically, you are creating an array that holds 10 references of type `JLabel`, and those references are referring to nothing (null) at the beginning:

```
JLabel stick[] = new JLabel[10];
```

So you need to create 10 instances of `JLabel` with `new JLabel()` and let those 10 references pointing to them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) stick[i] = new JLabel();
```

Comment: thanks!  this helped a lot! i thumbed up and chose this as my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a JLabel object in `stick[5]`?